How to get detailed error message when installing SQL Server Management Studio via chocolatey
I am trying to install SQL Server Management Studio  (SSMS) on an AWS EC2 instance via chocolatey. I am running this command:
choco install sql-server-management-studio -y

However, I get this error:
WARNING: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself 
- it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). 

Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\sql-server-management-studio_msi_install.log'"'. 
Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error.

ERROR: Running ["C:\Windows\TEMP\chocolatey\sql-server-management-studio\20.1.10\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe" /quiet /install /norestart /log "C:\Windows\TEMP\chocolatey\sql-server-management-studio\20.1.10\SSMS.MsiInstall.log" ] 
was not successful. Exit code was '1603'. Exit code indicates the following: Generic MSI Error. 
This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else 
(like the same version is already installed). 

Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\sql-server-management-studio_msi_install.log'"'. 
Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error..
  sql-server-management-studio may be able to be automatically uninstalled.


I have tried rebooting the instance and installing again but get the same error.
I do not already have SSMS installed on this instance.
I am able to install other software via chocolatey fine on this instance.
I searched online and understand that this is a generic error and would need to find more details to understand why it is failing. So my questions are:
Question 1)
How do I generate the MSI log like the error message suggests?
I tried running
choco install sql-server-management-studio -y 
      --install-arguments="'/l*v c:\sql-server-management-studio_msi_install.log'"

but this doesn't generate a log file
Question 2)
What fixes have worked for other people when encountering this issue?

Didn't you just ask this before?

In the first error message it mentioned the C:\Windows\TEMP\chocolatey\sql-server-management-studio\20.1.10\SSMS.MsiInstall.log log file. Have you looked in there for clues yet?

Hi @AlwaysLearning - yes, unfortunately it just shows the same error message as above

sorry @DaleK yeah but i uploaded an image of the error rather than than putting in text. Was informed not to do that and closed it. Reposted with correct format

Are you installing onto WS2016? Does it have .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later installed?

It's suggested by https://blog.aelterman.com/2016/05/23/performing-a-silent-install-of-sql-server-management-studio-2016/ to use /log for SSMS. I see you passed that and have a log file. Open up that log file and search for "Return Value 3" (minus the quotes). That's where you will find clues to the actual issue.

You should have edited your old question and asked for it to be reopened then

@AlwaysLearning yep, 2016 and it has. Net framework 4.8 installed

@DaleK OK, thank you noted for future reference
